# Trying to understand the difference of behavior between two inner join queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to optimize a query that uses an inner join, and I am puzzled by the difference of performance between two very similar queries.

I hope to shed some light on this.

The tables look like this:

Aggregates:

```
+-recid(key)-+-avg---+
+------------+-------+
```

History:

```
+-recid(key)-+-value-+
+------------+-------+
```

The aim is to get, for a given key (let's assume 1234), avg and value.

I have tried two queries who seem very similar to me:

```
SELECT a.avg, b.value FROM aggregates a, history b
WHERE a.recid = b.recid
AND a.recid = 1234
```

Takes 5 seconds to run

But,

```
SELECT a.avg, b.value FROM aggregates a, history b
WHERE a.recid = 1234
AND b.recid = 1234
```

runs in less than a second.

Those two queries give the very same result. I would like to understand the huge difference in performance (the end game being a better understanding, to achieve a better performance for this query!)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Different products optimize in different ways.

Comment: BTW, have you run the two queries multiple times, in different order? (Cold/hot data.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, it is very reproductible, one is consistently ~5 times slower than the other

Comment: Just because they yield the same result does not mean their execution paths are the same. Have a look at the actual execution path to find out why they are so different. One possible explanation could be that one of the tables contains significantly more rows than the other. It could also have to do with indexes on the tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, the engine used (AspenTech's SQLPlus does not expose the execution plan...) I guess this is bound to remain a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT a.avg, h.value
FROM aggregates a JOIN
     history h
     ON a.recid = h.recid
WHERE a.recid = 1234;
```

This doesn't affect performance, but it is the correct, modern syntax.

Assuming you have indexes on `aggregates(recid)` and `history(recid)`, then the two versions should have very similar execution plans in almost any database I can think of.  Those two indexes would be recommended for queries like this.

One possibility is cold versus warm cache.  The first time you run a query, the data needs to be loaded into memory.  That can take longer.  For proper timing, you need to take this into account.

Finally, if you really want to understand the difference, then you need to look at the execution plan.  Most databases provide a simple way to "explain" how the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure absolutely but it could be that your second query execution plan is already cached and thus DB optimizier didn't needed to bring one. BTW, your first query should be changes as below to use ANSI style JOIN syntax

```
SELECT a.avg, b.value FROM aggregates a
JOIN history b ON a.recid = b.recid
WHERE a.recid = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

The second query *might* be performing a cross join *then* filtering on the results though it would have to be a very old version of Oracle to be that dumb. But you need to look at the query plan to find out. If they consistently exhibit different performance then I guarantee the query plans will be different.